# Issue in drawing line with multi color android

Tags: android, view, colors, drawing

I was using this class to draw like pen tool with multi color it is working good but when i change color ,it does not change color in between choosing color.  i checked and try many solution they don't have any solution.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
Paint mPaint;
//MaskFilter  mEmboss;
//MaskFilter  mBlur;
Bitmap mBitmap;
Canvas mCanvas;
Path mPath;
Paint mBitmapPaint;
ProgressDialog pd;
String color;
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
private ArrayList<Integer> colorlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private float mX, mY;

public DrawingView(Context context, String color) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
     mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
     mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    paints.add(mPaint);
    colorlist.add(Color.parseColor(color));
    mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);


    if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    } else {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 250, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(canvas);
     canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    //  canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    int count = paints.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorlist.get(i));
        canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), mPaint);
    }


}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    //mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
    // mPath= new Path();
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();


    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);

            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return SMILEY;
}
```

}

i'm using this class to draw painting, i'm using this class in activity like this.

```
mDrawingView = new DrawingView(getApplicationContext(), color);
                mDrawingPad.addView(mDrawingView);
```

mDrawingPad is a linear layout in which i'm creating view.

Comment: how are you changing color in between ?

Comment: i'm changing color in draw method .

Comment: there is only one paint object in your paints list. that's why there is no change in color.

Comment: thanks, yeah i see my fault and rectify it. below answer is my solution in which i paired paint object with paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806208/regarding-android-paint-drawing-color)

I made some changes according to this solution in my code and finally i found it.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
Paint mPaint;
//MaskFilter  mEmboss;
//MaskFilter  mBlur;
Bitmap mBitmap;
Canvas mCanvas;
Path mPath;
Paint mBitmapPaint;
ProgressDialog pd;
String color;
ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> p = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
private float mX, mY;

public DrawingView(Context context, String color) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    //  mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    paints.add(mPaint);
    p.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(mPath, mPaint));

    //colorlist.put(mPath,color);
    mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);


    if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    } else {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 250, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    //  canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    for (Pair<Path, Paint> pp : p) {
        canvas.drawPath(pp.first, pp.second);
    }

}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPaint.setColor(ImageEditOptionActivity.pencolor);
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen

    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    //mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    p.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(mPath, mPaint));
    mPath.reset();
    mPath = new Path();
    //colorlist.put(mPath,color);
    mPaint = new Paint(mPaint);
    p.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(mPath, mPaint));


}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();


    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);

            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return SMILEY;
}
```

}